# Git commits not being reflected on Github contribution graphs

Tags: git, github, github-pages, commit

I've been working on a small project, which I've been committing to without further issues. The problem began last Friday when I made about 5 commits and none of them are reflected on my GitHub Contribution Chart.

The weird thing happes when I check on the command details by adding .patch at the end of it, as per the GitHub documentation. It shows an incorrect email address that I don't know where it's coming from, the email address shown there is: manudequevedo@gmail.comm instead of manudequevedo@gmail.com. I've looked everywhere to find that email address and I simply can do it.

Something important to mention, the page is published within the GH Pages, here is the link to the repository:
[Repository Link](https://github.com/ManudeQuevedo/FEM-newsletter-signup)

Could someone point me to the right steps to get this sorted out?

The steps I've taken so far ar these:

- Terminal command: `git config --global user.name`, which shows the correct name
- Terminal command: `git config --global user.mail`, which also shows the correct email address (manudequevedo@gmail.com)
- I even had run the `git config` command without the `--global` directly on the repository I'm working at.

I have also checked in the GitHub settings that the email does match with the one registered on the site. It all does match!

I even re-configured the `git config --global user.name` and `user.email` to see if that would make a change. I have also removed the email address from GitHub and  added it back again, with no success.

Comment: Try this `git log --all --format="%h -- %ae -- %ce" | grep -F @gmail.comm` to check if that wrong email is in existing commits.

Comment: Thank! it seems all of the commits are with the wrong email, What makes it even weirder is that even the first commit that does appear on the contribution graph has the same error on the email, after that no commit appears in the contributions graph.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+email+multiple+commits `git filter-repo` should be the best.